# I cannot create ImageView once I copied picture in Android app's res folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, resources

So I've got a relatively simple problem. I copied a picture to res/drawble-hdpi folder and I can see even in R.java that eclipse created static final int address for that picture BUT once I choose Image View from eclipse Palette the resource chooser doesn't show up my previously added picture ! It shows only ic_launcher.

I tried to clean up my project but that didn't help. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try right clicking on your project and selecting "refresh"?

Comment: Okey, problem solved guys! I just created a new project and its fine now. I supposed I messed something up in project's guts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate **drawable** folder under **res** folder then put your images in that then access them now and you'd best place  .png image files in that folder..

When accessing these image files programmingly.set an image for an ImageView for example:

```
Drawable imgDrawable=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourImageFileName));
imgView.setImageDrawable(imgDrawable);
```

May it helps you.

Comment: He doesn't need to create a drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the picture using `android:src="@drawable/yourImageName"` inside your `<ImageView/>` in the XML file that contains it.

Comment: I tried that, It simply says "No resource found" even though name is correct.

Comment: Make sure you do not have `android.R.*` as part of your imports.